# Resultset relative skips last record in Java/Access

Tags: java, mysql, resultset

My Database :

```
+---------+-----------+---------------+-------------------+---------------+-----------------+--------------------+
| KlantId | KlantNaam | KlantVoornaam | KlantAdres        | KlantPostcode | KlantWoonplaats | KlantGeboorteDatum |
+---------+-----------+---------------+-------------------+---------------+-----------------+--------------------+
|       1 | Vervoort  | Dieter        | Grootstraat 1     |          3500 | Hasselt         | 1/01/1991          |
|       2 | Droogmans | Jos           | Kleine Laan 2     |          3500 | Hasselt         | 5/05/1999          |
|       3 | Severijns | Sarah         | Brede Weg 3       |          3570 | Alken           | 28/02/1972         |
|       4 | Peeters   | Piet          | Rondplein 4       |          3600 | Genk            | 6/08/1973          |
|       5 | Vreemans  | Veerle        | Lange Boulevard 5 |          3500 | Hasselt         | 4/04/1980          |
+---------+-----------+---------------+-------------------+---------------+-----------------+--------------------+
```

My code where I read it :

```
try {

    System.out.println("De klanten zijn:");
    if (!rs.relative(1)) {
        rs.first(); 
    } 
    System.out.println("Naam en voornaam: " + rs.getString("KlantVoornaam") + " " + rs.getString("KlantNaam"));
    ShowMenu();

    con.close();
} catch (SQLException e) {
    System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    System.exit(0);
}
```

For some odd reason `rs.relative(1)` returns false on the 4th record (`"Peeters Piet"`) while there is still one left (`"Vreemans Veerle"`) and so it returns to the first record.

Is this a mistake in `rs.relative()` or in my code?

I know that I could do this with

```
if (!rs.next()) {
     rs.first(); 
}
```

But I'm wondering why `rs.relative(1)` doesn't do the same job.

Comment: Does your query have any WHERE condition?

Comment: @PabloLozano No, and using `rs.next()` returns the right records, so I don't think it's my query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

API documentation explicity says:

> Note: Calling the method relative(1) is identical to calling the
>   method next() and calling the method relative(-1) is identical to
>   calling the method previous().

So I don't think it should be any difference. Try to debug it, or just add `getRow()` values in a System.out.println before calling `relative(1)` to check in which line you are.

EDIT: Looking your [code](http://pastebin.com/eksA2bV3) I cannot figure out why is failing, but be aware that ShowMenu should not be called by the rest of the methods: you are chaining calls in the stack.It's very hard to produce it manually, but enough user interactions could crash the application. A better way to do that is having a loop in showMenu(), which would be broken when user press 5.

**SOLUTION**: You're right, the issue is the mySQL implementation of ResultSet. Check [this](http://www.docjar.com/docs/api/com/mysql/jdbc/ResultSet.html#relative%28int%29) API doc, where mySQL code says EXACTLY THE OPPOSITE as we expected (Current version of the driver renamed this class to com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetImpl, but the comment remains there):

> Note: Calling relative(1) is different than calling next() since is
>   makes sense to call next() when there is no current row, for example,
>   when the cursor is positioned before the first row or after the last
>   row of the result set.

And method names should start with lowercase (following Java conventions makes code more readable for others ;) )

Comment: http://pastebin.com/eksA2bV3 , I have some translations at the top, that's my entire code, it shows a printStream menu, chooses an action, and then shows the printstream menu again (Sort of a loop)

Comment: Also, the api you found is probably for javax.xml.xquery , and not for java.sql.ResultSet; EDIT: My mistake , the api does indeed say that

Comment: Thanks, it's honestly more starting to feel like a java error/api mistake more than an error in my code

Comment: We can try to check that part: ResultSet is an interface. Check what the real class of your ResultSet is and maybe its code can be examined (if it's a open source implementation)

Comment: Checked, updated answer: the bug is the mySQL implementation of java.sql.ResultSet

Comment: Ah yes, but I don't understand why that bugs occurs in my simple code, thanks alot though